# How to use $mergeObjects to merge arrays corresponding to existing groups?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, grouping, aggregation

I'm trying to merge two arrays in my aggregation pipeline. After performing $facet, my MongoDB document has this format:

```
{
  "final": [
    {
      "key": "TP-1",
      "status_map": [
        {  "status": "Closed", "final": [ "a", "b"]},
        { "status": "Done", "final": ["c","d" ] }
      ]
    },
    {
      "key": "TP-2",
      "status_map": [
        { "status": "Closed", "final": [  "x","y"] }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "start": [
    {
      "key": "TP-1",
      "status_map": [
        { "status": "Closed", "start": [ "h"]},
        { "status": "Done", "start": ["a"]}
      ]
    },
    {
      "key": "TP-2",
      "status_map": [{ "status": "Done", "start": ["l","m"]}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output:

I need to merge `final` and `start` array corresponding to two groups:

1. Based on `key` and then
2. Based on `status`

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "key": "TP-1",
      "status_map": [
        { "status": "Closed","final": ["a","b"],"start":["h"]},
        { "status": "Done","final": ["c","d"],"start":["a"]}
        ]
    },
    {
      "key": "TP-2",
      "status_map": [
        { "status": "Closed",  "final":[ "x","y"],"start": []},
        { "status": "Done",  "final": [ ],"start": [ "l","m"]}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How to achieve this use case?

Comment: Are there situations that you need to merge the array `final` or `start`? I.e for the same key and status, could there be different objects that you need to merge together and combine `final` and `start`? In your example there is only one object for each key and status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this, not necessarily with `$mergeObjects`. But since you mentioned `$mergeObjects` this is one that uses it:

Note that, with this approach, we are merging objects of the same key and status, the values in the arrays will not get concatenated if the same key exists for multiple documents, The arrays will get replaced instead.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      all: { $concatArrays: ["$final","$start"] }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$all"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$all.status_map"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",  // keep _id in $group to apply the group for each document, otherwise if you want to apply group on all documents, omit this
        key: "$all.key",
        status: "$all.status_map.status"
      },
      status_map: { $mergeObjects: "$$ROOT.all.status_map" }
    }
  },
  { // some data don't have start or end at all, we have to set a default empty array
    $addFields: { // you can skip this stage if you allow data without start and final keys
      "status_map.start": { $ifNull: ["$status_map.start", []] },
      "status_map.final": { $ifNull: ["$status_map.final", []] }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { _id: "$_id._id", key: "$_id.key" },
      key: { $first: "$_id.key" },
      status_map: { $push: "$status_map" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3Ipp52LyVJl)

Answer (score 1):

With no assumptions (for example for both keys to always appear) my strategy was to concat both arrays, unwind and finally group by the key.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      concat: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$final",
          "$start"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$concat"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$concat.status_map"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        k: "$concat.key",
        status: "$concat.status_map.status"
      },
      final: {
        $push: "$concat.status_map.final"
      },
      start: {
        $push: "$concat.status_map.start"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.k",
      status_map: {
        $push: {
          status: "$_id.status",
          final: "$final",
          start: "$start"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      key: "$_id",
      status_map: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BjfU3jDIZbG)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I also need status level grouping inside grouped keys having both ```start ``` and ```final```  arrays inside a particular ```status```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Tom Slabbaert's answer,

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E6RongINfpL)

Here, final and start array is of format `array of array`. But It has to be simply an `array`.

It can be achieved by using `$unwind` on `status_map` and `$reduce` on `status_map.final` and `status_map.start` arrays.

Final query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      concat: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$final",
          "$start"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$concat"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$concat.status_map"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        k: "$concat.key",
        status: "$concat.status_map.status"
      },
      final: {
        $push: "$concat.status_map.final"
      },
      start: {
        $push: "$concat.status_map.start"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.k",
      status_map: {
        $push: {
          status: "$_id.status",
          final: "$final",
          start: "$start"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      key: "$_id",
      status_map: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$status_map"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      key: 1,
      "status_map.status": 1,
      final: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$status_map.final",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      start: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$status_map.start",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$key",
      status_map: {
        $push: {
          status: "$status_map.status",
          final: "$final",
          start: "$start"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zRQsI2hVLoa)